# How do I move a mesh in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am trying to make a car spawner in roblox studio but I don't know how to move the mesh. I think I can use a pivot but I don't know how.

Comment: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/BasePart/Position

Answer (score 1):

google "roblox mesh"

click first hit: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Mesh-Parts

read.

"This will insert a [MeshPart](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/MeshPart) instance with your mesh applied".

Further down click https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/positioning-objects

> The global position of an object is determined by its three Position
> properties: X, Y, and Z. This position is based on the center of the
> object.
>
> To position an object in Roblox Studio, use the Move tool located in
> the Home or Model tabs. Alternatively, you can set the Position
> properties directly in the Properties window.

Make sure you also read  https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/MeshPart

Now you know that your mesh results in a MeshPart which happens to have a Position property which determins the position of the MeshPart which your mesh is applied to.

Comment: The MeshPart does not stay on the car. Btw I took it from the toolbox